# JavaFX adding new window signature

Tags: java, javafx

Just trying to add another window to some sample JavaFX code provided in my book. Here is the new window with a button that I would like to add:

```
    Button btNO = new Button("NO");
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(BtOK, 200, 250);
    Stage stage1 = new Stage();
    stage1.setTitle("Third stage");
    stage1.setScene(scene1);
    stage1.show();
```

I looked at this code (which compiles correctly) and tried to emulate it but simplify it a bit more over a line or two extra to better see what is going on, but couldn't quite get it right. Could be that I'm dead tired today. Here's the other code that works:

```
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("Second stage");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(new Button("New Stage"), 100, 100));
    stage.show();
```

Also, yes there is a primary stage but not sure why its different from this (still learning)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Questions of the form "here's my code, please debug it" are considered off-topic. StackOverflow is not a discussion, tutorial or debugging site. The way this works is you are expected to attempt to solve the problem and then ask for help when you run into a difficulty, explaining clearly what you have tried and what you don't understand. At a minimum you should already have stepped through the code in an IDE debugger and be able to identify results that don't match your expectation.

Comment: What actually goes wrong with the code you tried?